# DNN error using startupscript when not logged in

Tags: javascript, c#, telerik, dotnetnuke

I am trying to execute code in DNN.

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "ShowBAP('Grinder', '" + a + "');", true);
```

When a user is logged in, this works fine.  However, when there is no user logged in, and you access this page anonymously, the following error gets occurs. (from Telerik.Web.UI.WebRe...)

Uncaught Error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
    at Function.Error.create (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a0506169f-fccc-46f8-a5ec-5e7be35dfbdd%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2013.2.717.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a636548d2-ff28-4c99-b077-b4b8ed4e8c55%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc:6)
    at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._createPageRequestManagerServerError (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a0506169f-fccc-46f8-a5ec-5e7be35dfbdd%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2013.2.717.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a636548d2-ff28-4c99-b077-b4b8ed4e8c55%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc:15)
    at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._parseDelta (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a0506169f-fccc-46f8-a5ec-5e7be35dfbdd%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2013.2.717.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a636548d2-ff28-4c99-b077-b4b8ed4e8c55%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc:15)
    at Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager._onFormSubmitCompleted (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a0506169f-fccc-46f8-a5ec-5e7be35dfbdd%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2013.2.717.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a636548d2-ff28-4c99-b077-b4b8ed4e8c55%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc:15)
    at Array. (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a0506169f-fccc-46f8-a5ec-5e7be35dfbdd%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2013.2.717.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a636548d2-ff28-4c99-b077-b4b8ed4e8c55%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc:6)
    at Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a0506169f-fccc-46f8-a5ec-5e7be35dfbdd%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2013.2.717.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a636548d2-ff28-4c99-b077-b4b8ed4e8c55%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc:6
    at Sys.Net.WebRequest.completed (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a0506169f-fccc-46f8-a5ec-5e7be35dfbdd%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2013.2.717.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a636548d2-ff28-4c99-b077-b4b8ed4e8c55%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc:6)
    at XMLHttpRequest._onReadyStateChange (Telerik.Web.UI.WebResource.axd?_TSM_HiddenField_=ScriptManager_TSM&compress=1&_TSM_CombinedScripts_=%3b%3bSystem.Web.Extensions%2c+Version%3d4.0.0.0%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d31bf3856ad364e35%3aen-US%3a0506169f-fccc-46f8-a5ec-5e7be35dfbdd%3aea597d4b%3ab25378d2%3bTelerik.Web.UI%2c+Version%3d2013.2.717.40%2c+Culture%3dneutral%2c+PublicKeyToken%3d121fae78165ba3d4%3aen-US%3a636548d2-ff28-4c99-b077-b4b8ed4e8c55%3a16e4e7cd%3af7645509%3aed16cbdc:6)

I am not sure what the problem is, any suggestions?

Comment: What is `a`? Could it be that it is NULL? Because `RegisterStartupScript` can be used at any time, not only for logged in users.

Comment: sorry, a is - Request.IsAuthenticated

Comment: however, even when I remove that variable from the code, the error is still being thrown.

Comment: at JH.checkauth.View.SelectGSeries(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)          This is the error that shows up on the Event Viewer in DNN

Comment: Then the problem is probably in `JH.checkauth.View.SelectGSeries`, whatever that may be and not with the ScriptManager. It looks like a custom/purchased DNN module?

Comment: SelectGSeries is the parent void where I am calling RegisterStartupScript,    `public void SelectGSeries(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button btn = (Button)sender;
        lbtnBCGSeries.Text = btn.Text;

        hfSeries.Value = btn.Attributes["data-code"].ToString();

        pGSeries.Visible = false;

        pBAP.Visible = true;

        string a = "USD";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, GetType(), "showalert", "ShowBAP('Grinder', '" + a + "');", true);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue, I was calling a user controller before being authenticated. which was throwing an error.